# ChartJS fails to render horizontal bar chart for timeseries data

Tags: javascript, chart.js, bar-chart, timeserieschart

Here's a plunker 
https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/49kIfy8OShzlzu5J
that explains the issue.

If the chart `type` is changed to `bar` or `line` it works fine. But it fails to render a `horizontalBar` - there are no errors or warnings to indicate any issue, if any.

Does the `horizontalBar` require a user to set the labels manually and explicitly or is there a configuration setting I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `horizontalBar`, you must make sure your `yAxis` is defined as `type: 'time'`. Your data must also reflect this and provide the data for the correct axis.

```
{ y: '2020-01-01T00:00:00', x: Math.random() * 20 }
```

This could look as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Line Chart</title>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
    <style>
      canvas {
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div style="height: 450px; width: 300px">
      <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
    <script>
      const config = {
        type: 'horizontalBar',
        options: {
          title: { text: 'Bar Chart', display: true },
          responsive: true,
          maintainAspectRatio: false,
          scales: {
            yAxes: [
              {
                offset: true,
                type: 'time'
              },
            ]
          },
        },
        data: {
          datasets: [
            {
              label: 'Label 1',
              borderColor: '#40407a',
              backgroundColor: '#d1ccc0',
              borderWidth: 3,
              data: [
                { y: '2020-01-01T00:00:00', x: Math.random() * 20 },
                { y: '2020-01-01T01:00:00', x: Math.random() * 20 },
                { y: '2020-01-01T01:20:00', x: Math.random() * 20 },
                { y: '2020-01-01T02:10:00', x: Math.random() * 20 },
                { y: '2020-01-01T02:35:00', x: Math.random() * 20 },
                { y: '2020-01-01T03:00:00', x: Math.random() * 20 },
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
      };

      window.onload = function() {
        var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
        window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, config);
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The documentation is a bit confusing, it says "any options specified on the x axis in a bar chart, are applied to the y axis in a horizontal bar chart" - which implies that the library takes care of using the appropriate options. Thanks for pointing out that we can manually switch the x-axes and y-axes configuration to achieve this.